# Cannot add new value to MongoDB's BSON field using Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a document with the field `admins` and am looking to add new users into this field. The value for these new users is a simple number string.

```
def modify_admin(identity, doc)
  ip_addr = "127.0.0.1:27017"
  client = Mongo::Client.new([ip_addr], :database => "camp")
  if doc[0] == 'r'
    doc = doc[2..-1] 
    client[:inventory].update_one({"name": doc}, {$push => {"admins" => identity}})
  client.close
end
```

The collection I'm trying to add is in this line: `client[:inventory].update_one({"name": doc}, {$push => {"admins" => identity}})`,

However I am running into the error `NilClass instances are not allowed as keys in a BSON document. (BSON::InvalidKey)`.

I have tried different syntax for the `$push` method but nothing seems to work.

My document structure is as follows, I'm using symbols as the field value.

```
document = {:name => build_array[1], :owner => identity, :admins => identity}
```

How can I add new values to the `:owner` field using Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$push` in ruby usually means global variable. So, all you need is to wrap $push operation into parentheses:

```
- client[:inventory].update_one({"name": doc}, {$push => {"admins" => identity}})
+ client[:inventory].update_one({"name": doc}, {"$push" => {"admins" => identity}})
```

And you should be fine